# Get ip and subnetmask using command sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

So I want to get my ip adress and subnetmask. The output of ifconfig should be "pasted" to sed. So sed should modify the output in order to get only the ip and subnet mask.

Like:

```
ifconfig | sed -n -e s/:127\.0\.0\.1 //g -e s/ *inet addr:\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/gp
```

Edit:

```
ifconfig | sed -rn '/((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/p'
```

With this I got the subnet mask and the ip BUT I also got Bcast. How can I change the regex to get only subnet mask and ip?

Output of edit:

```
inet Adresse:192.168.142.191 
 Bcast:192.168.255.255  
 Maske:255.255.0.0
 inet Adresse:127.0.0.1 
 Maske:255.0.0.0
```

I want this output:

```
inet Adresse:192.168.142.191 
Maske:255.255.0.0
```

Comment: ipconfig or ifconfig? would be useful if you add output before using sed as well your final expected output

Comment: @Sundeep see edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ifconfig | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '/inet / {gsub("addr:", "", $2); print $2}; /netmask / {gsub("netmask", "", $2); print $4};'
```

It's output exclude loopback interface "lo 127.0.0.1". And gives to you and output like this:

```
10.0.0.1
255.255.0.0
192.168.1.46
255.255.255.0
```

One line per ip or mask. Or you can specify only one interface doing `ifconfig eth0` instead of `ifconfig`. In this way you print only desired interface.

If you want the exact format with the "inet", "Adresse", etc. You can add it to awk:

```
ifconfig | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '/inet / {gsub("addr:", "", $2); print "inet Adresse:"$2}; /netmask / {gsub("netmask", "", $2); print "Maske:"$4};'
```

Its output is:

```
inet Adresse:10.0.0.1
Maske:255.255.0.0
inet Adresse:192.168.1.46
Maske:255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did not use like this:

```
ifconfig |sed -n 's/inet addr:\(.*\)Bcast:.*Mask:\(.*\)/\1 \2/p'
```

But you need more concrete regex for ip. You can find it in google.

Answer (score 0):

Consider combining the *-n* option and the search and replace command *s/regexp/replacement/*. Make it match the whole line and replace it with only the bits you need:

```
ifconfig | sed -rn 's/^.*(inet[0-9. ]+netmask[0-9. ]+).*$/\1/p'
```

Your *ifconfig* output seems to be different from mine so you might need to change the *inet* and *netmask* parts for it to work on your system.